# NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.CompletionMessage was not registered in the serializer

Tags: nservicebus

A suite of integration services that use NServiceBus have been dropped in my lap (unfortunately I was not involved in the original implementation and the person who did write the code has left).

The services work fine in our development & testing environments; but I cannot get them to run in our production environment.  I get the error

```
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.CompletionMessage was not registered in the serializer. 
Check that it appears in the list of configured assemblies/types to scan.
```

I've checked the config files on the servers and they're almost identical; in particular the `MsmqTransportConfig` and `UnicastBusConfig` blocks are identical.  The major difference between the two environments is that in production, the web/app/database tiers are on separate servers whereas in the testing environment they all reside on the same server.  However, the integration service calls are only made from the app tier, and even in production the app tier and integration services reside on the same server (at least for now), so I'm not sure this should make a difference.

I did download the documentation (the .chm file) but every topic I click on says "broken link".

I've also read several the questions and answers including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005441/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-module-was-ex), but since the code is working in our testing environment I'm somewhat reluctant to make changes to it.

We're configuring NServiceBus as follows:

```
        NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()
            .Log4Net()
            .StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.Container)
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(true)
                .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
            .UnicastBus()
                .LoadMessageHandlers()
                .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
```

and the transport is configured like so:

```
  <MsmqTransportConfig
    InputQueue="OutboundSubscriptionRequestQueue"
    ErrorQueue="error"
    NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"
    MaxRetries="5"
  />

  <UnicastBusConfig
    DistributorControlAddress=""
    DistributorDataAddress=""
    ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="">
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

I would really appreciate any assistance.  I'm not necessarily looking to have an answer handed to me, just a nudge in the right direction ... right now I feel as though I'm shooting in the dark.

Comment: Make sure you unblock the help file after downloading it.

Comment: Ah ... thanks Udi, I have not had to do that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like nsb fails to scan nservicebus.core.dll for types. Can you verify that its present, not blocked and that log4net.dll is deployed in the same dir.

Comment: Both DLLs are present.  
Can you be more specific about blocking?  I checked to see if there were any alternate data streams using `dir /r` and I didn't see anything.

Comment: Right click on the dll and make suru that it doesn't say that it's "blocked"

Comment: ... the same as I did for the help file.  I seem to be a little slow this week, sorry (and thanks for your patience).  I did check and the file doesn't seem to be blocked (nor is log4net.dll).  I guess I just need to grab the samples and starting working through them; unfortunately that's almost certainly going to make my boss pretty unhappy ...

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523025/nservicebus-type-was-not-registered-in-the-serializer-fix

Comment: Yes; I was just about to post the results.  (I had looked for something like this on StackOverflow and not found it; but this seems to be a fairly common issue with ASP.NET even when not using NServiceBus, so I had stumbled upon this procedure elsewhere.)  

That does appear to have resolved the immediate issue.  (Messages still aren't getting published to the bus, though, so i still have some work to do.)  Thank you.