# NServiceBus - Type was not registered in the serializer - Fix?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, nservicebus, application-pool

We are using NServiceBus in a web application and each time we deploy our code to production, we have to delete the Temporary Files in the folder:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

We are following the instructions here to fix this:

```
http://www.nservicebus.com/faq/TypeNotRegisteredInSerializer.aspx
```

I was wondering if there is a more permanent fix to this? I feel like I am fighting with this every time I deploy new code. What is the best way to handle this from code? If that doesn't work, is it best to just stop the application pools, delete the files, and restart the app pools every time I deploy new code?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using Configure.WithWeb(), try instead:

```
Configure.With(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory)
```

That way, it will search the actual bin folder in your deployed web application instead of the temporary folder. This is also the default behavior in nservicebus 3.0.

Comment: Thanks!!! I was struggeling with an old solution and this helped!

Answer (score 1):

We've hit this too.  Haven't found anything better than stopping the app pools, deleting the temp asp.net files and then restarting.

Comment: I wrote a bash script and am using psexec from Hudson to automate this for me now. It was the only thing I could think of so I could take care of it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

What is the solution if you have some assemblies that should be ignored. We have something like this:

```
_bus = Configure.With(AllAssemblies.Except("IncompatibleAssembly.dll"))
```